# Inherited font-size is not overridden by the element's style when using em

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the parent's `font-size:0` and the child's `font-size:10em`. I am doing this to remove the annoying space in between the in-line blocks.

Code sample:

```css
div.bully {
    font-size:0em;
}

div.geek {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="bully">
    <div class="geek">Something wise</div>
    <div class="geek">Something wiser</div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/r3rc0t1d/

It doesn't work, for some reason, the child's style does not override the parent's. I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox and IE. However, it works if I change it to <kbd>px</kbd> (http://jsfiddle.net/r3rc0t1d/1/). Is there any reason why <kbd>em</kbd> doesn't work but <kbd>px</kbd> works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `em`, your font-sizes will always be *relative* to the parent's font size. So, if you're setting the font-size of the parent to `0em` and the child's font size to `10em`, you're telling the box to apply a font-size of

```
10 * 0em = 0em
```

Comment: Wow, that makes perfect sense, in other words if I choose to hide that space inbetween the inline-blocks with font size then I cannot use `em` for sizes.

Comment: See [this excellent article](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids) for some further information about the usage of `em` s for layouts.